# Can I measure induction motor parameters with measurement tools?

Tags: motor, simulation, measurement, induction-motor, reactive-power

I want to simulate a induction motor in ngspice so I need to model the induction motor as described [here](https://myelectrical.com/notes/entryid/251/induction-motor-equivalent-circuit). I must calculate the model parameters as described [here](https://people.ucalgary.ca/%7Eaknigh/electrical_machines/induction/i_params.html).

My questions are:
Can I measure the DC resistance with a DMM and inductances with an LCR meter? If not, how can I measure or calculate the reactive power of a motor?

Comment: A LOT of motors have detailed datasheets.

Comment: @mkeith The motor is for a old washing machine.

Comment: Oh, I see. Probably no part number and even if there is, there won't be detailed data.

Comment: If it's from a washing machine then there's a fair old chance it isn't an induction motor. Pictures (especially of the nameplate) are vital here. Have you googled the washing machine model number looking for parts lists and possible repair shops that might be able to give more details about the motor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can measure inductance and DC resistance in that way.

The locked rotor and no-load tests will need to be done with the motor powered from a variable source (eg a variable autotransformer)

It may be possible to use a plug-in power-meter like kill-a-volt(tm) to make the current measurements. else use an AC ammeter (your multimeter if it supports that) power factor is going to need a power meter of some sort (again the kill-a-volt if you don't need a measurement that's traceable to some standard)

Comment: Can i model the motor simply with a serie inductor and resistor with measured values? Actually i want to simulate a Triac's Snuber circuit that will controls that motor.

Comment: it's complicated because the cage winding on the rotor forms a shorted turn which will reduce the measured inductance, probably in a frequency dependant way.